# Qt-Designer costumn widgets and relative path

Tags: qt, widget, qt-designer

I am trying to create unit testing for my project but struggle with costumn widgets.
While compiling the test unit, `ui_mainwindow.h` cannot find my `widget.h` anymore.
My project structure looks like this:

```
Project
    scr
        scr.pro
        scr.pri
        mainwindow.ui
        CostumnWidgets
            widget.h
    test
        test.pro
```

In Qt-Designer i refer to my widget with `./CostumnWidgets/widget.h`

scr.pri

```
QT       += core gui
TEMPLATE = app
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += $$PWD/mainwindow.cpp \
    $$PWD/CostumnWidgets/widget.cpp

HEADERS  += $$PWD/mainwindow.h \
    $$PWD/CostumnWidgets/widget.h

FORMS    += $$PWD/mainwindow.ui
```

test.pro

```
TARGET = Test
include(../scr/scr.pri)

QT += widgets
QT += testlib

SOURCES += $$PWD/test.cpp
```

How can I solve that without making a copy of my CostumnWidget-folder to my test directory?
Thank you!

Comment: Try to add to .pro file `INCLUDEPATH += <your path>`. Btw, do you mean **custom** widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154980/how-to-structure-project-while-unit-testing-qt-app-by-qtestlib). There various solutions for this. Simplest is marked as an answer there.

Comment: Thank you that works! Although the path has to be `../../framework` instead of `../../../framework`. Not sure whether that is wrong in the other question or just specific to my project structure. What I do not understand: I guess the path generated in `build\ui_mainwindow.h` is relative to the `*pro-file` and not to `ui_mainwindow.h` is sthat right? Otherwise I do not understand how it could find that file in first place. Also: When I only change the path in either the `*pri-file` or Qt-Designer, it always seems to take the "incorrect" path. How is it decided which path to use?